# Нужно перемещать объект касанием пальца по экрану

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, augmented-reality

```
void moveObject()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        TouchPosition = touch.position;

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Ray ray = ARcamera.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
            RaycastHit hitObject;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitObject))
            {
                if (hitObject.collider.CompareTag("UnSelected"))
                {
                    hitObject.collider.gameObject.tag = "Selected";
                }
            }
        }

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            ARRaycastManagerScript.Raycast(TouchPosition, hits);
            SelectedObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("Selected");
            SelectedObject.transform.position = hits[0].pose.position;
        }

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            if (SelectedObject.CompareTag("Selected"))
            {
                SelectedObject.tag = "UnSelected";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Речь идет об ассистенте дополненной реальности. Мне нужно сделать так, что-бы его можно было перемещать касанием пальца по экрану. Вроде в юнити все как надо настроил, но все равно не работает: ничего не происходит при нажатии на объект. Возможно, какая-то проблема в коде?

Comment: "не работает" - это как расшифровывается? ошибка или что?

Comment: спасибо за комментарий! нет, ошибок никаких нет, просто не получается передвигать объект пальцем - при нажатии на объект ничего не происходит(

Comment: ну так и напишите в вопросе, вопрос можно редактировать

Comment: спасибо Вам большое за комментарии! все, исправил!:)

Comment: Почему `hitObject.collider.gameObject` нельзя сразу сохранить в переменную? Зачем пользоваться супер дорогой `FindWithTag`, **КАЖДЫЙ КАДР**? `camera.ScreenPointToRay` я понимаю куда рейкаст... `ARRaycastManagerScript.Raycast` а это куда?

Comment: то есть мы объекту который нужно двигать присваиваем булевую переменную(заранее установленную на false) и если происходит касание в области объекта которого нужно двигать, то мы эту переменную ставим на true, и если эта переменная стоит на true то мы выполняем код который отвечает за то что мы пальцем двигаем объект? и насчет ARRaycastManagerScript.Raycast - это Вы имели ввиду то что в коде не дописано то что мы хотим отслеживать?